# Syntax highlighter in html/php page

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I am developing and online code judge project.
I am using Php as my scripting language.

In the code compilation page.. where a user writes the code,i want to use syntax highlighting for different programming languages..

Are there any ways to do it?

I tried `SyntaxHighlighter - Alex Gorbatchev` but couldn't make it to work

here is the code :

```
<?php
/*

 * Solution submission page
 */
    require_once('functions.php');
    if(!loggedin())
        header("Location: login.php");
    else
        include('header.php');
        connectdb();
?>
              <li><a href="index.php">Problems</a></li>
              <li><a href="submissions.php">Submissions</a></li>
              <li><a href="scoreboard.php">Scoreboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['terror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-warning\">\nYour program exceeded the time limit. Maybe you should improve your algorithm.\n</div>");
        if(isset($_GET['cerror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\n<strong>The following errors occured:</strong><br/>\n<pre>\n".$_SESSION['cerror']."\n</pre>\n</div>");
        else if(isset($_GET['oerror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nYour program output did not match the solution for the problem. Please check your program and try again.\n</div>");
        else if(isset($_GET['lerror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nYou did not use one of the allowed languages. Please use a language that is allowed.\n</div>");
        else if(isset($_GET['serror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nCould not connect to the compiler server. Please contact the admin to solve the problem.\n</div>");
        else if(isset($_GET['derror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nPlease enter all the details asked before you can continue!\n</div>");
        else if(isset($_GET['ferror']))
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nPlease enter a legal filename.\n</div>");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM prefs";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $accept = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $query = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $status = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($accept['accept'] == 0)
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nSubmissions are closed now!\n</div>");
        if($status['status'] == 0)
          echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">\nYou have been banned. You cannot submit a solution.\n</div>");
      ?>
    <h1><small>Submit Solution</small></h1>
      <?php
        // display the problem statement
        if(isset($_GET['id']) and is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM problems WHERE sl='".$_GET['id']."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            include('markdown.php');
        $out = Markdown($row['text']);
        echo("<hr/>\n<h1>".$row['name']."</h1>\n");
        echo($out);
      ?>
      <br/><span class="label label-info">Time Limit: <?php echo($row['time']/1000); ?> seconds</span>
      <hr/>
      <?php
        // get the peviously submitted solution if exists
        if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM solve WHERE (problem_id='".$_GET['id']."' AND username='".$_SESSION['username']."')";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
          $fields = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="eval.php">
      <?php if($num == 0)
          echo('<input type="hidden" name="ctype" value="new"/>');
        else
          echo('<input type="hidden" name="ctype" value="change"/>');
      ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) echo($_GET['id']);?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="lang" id="hlang" value="<?php if($num == 0) echo('c'); else echo($fields['lang']);?>"/>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <div id="blank"></div>
        <a id="lang" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Language: 
        <?php
          if($num == 0) echo('C');
          else if($fields['lang']=='c') echo('C');
          else if($fields['lang']=='cpp') echo('C++');
          else if($fields['lang']=='java') echo('Java');
          else if($fields['lang']=='python') echo('Python');
        ?>
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" onclick="changeLang('C');">C</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="changeLang('C++');">C++</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="changeLang('Java');">Java</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="changeLang('Python');">Python</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <br/>
      Filename: <input class="span8" type="text" id="filename" name="filename" value="<?php if(!($num == 0)) echo($fields['filename']);?>"/>
      <br/>Type your program below:<br/><br/>
      <textarea style="font-family: mono; height:400px;" class="span9" name="soln" id="text"><?php if(!($num == 0)) echo($fields['soln']);?></textarea><br/>
      <?php if($accept['accept'] == 1 and $status['status'] == 1) echo("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Run\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large\"/>");
            else echo("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Run\" class=\"btn disabled btn-large\" disabled=\"disabled\"/>");
      ?>
      <span class="label label-info">You are allowed to use any of the following languages: 
      <?php $txt="";
        if($accept['c'] == 1) $txt = "C, ";
        if($accept['cpp'] == 1) $txt = $txt."C++, ";
        if($accept['java'] == 1) $txt = $txt."Java, ";
        if($accept['python'] == 1) $txt = $txt."Python, ";
        $final = substr($txt, 0, strlen($txt) - 2);
        echo($final."</span>\n");
      ?>
      </form>
      <?php
    }
      ?>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script language="javascript">
      function changeLang(lang) {
        $('#lang').remove();
        $('#blank').after('<a id="lang" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Language: ' + lang + ' <span class="caret"></span></a>');
        if(lang == 'C')
          $('#hlang').val('c');
        else if(lang== 'C++')
          $('#hlang').val('cpp');
        else if(lang== 'Java')
          $('#hlang').val('java');
        else if(lang== 'Python')
          $('#hlang').val('python');
      }
    </script>
<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what did not work as you wanted it to, because SH works well for many people?

Comment: I could not understand how to use the <code> tag where and how ..

i want something such that the text is highlighted as and when the user writes a code..

Comment: Ah, you don't want a syntax highlighter but a web code editor.  One moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a "syntax highlighter" that will correctly format a chunk of code to display it optimally, and a syntax highlighting code editor, that allows a user to enter code that will be colored according to the selected language's syntax.

For the latter I have been using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) which works very well.  But there are many other solutions, the [relevant WikiPedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors) contains an extensive list and a feature comparison.

EDIT: to get you started: start by reading [the manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html), it shows the different possible scenarios for integrating CodeMirror in your code.  I think that in your case just using a simple `CodeMirror.fromTextArea()` should get you started.  CodeMirror comes with tons of examples, [like this one highlighting php](http://codemirror.net/mode/php/index.html).  Have a look at the source code, I pasted the relevant part here below:

```
<form><textarea id="code" name="code">
<?php
function hello($who) {
    return "Hello " . $who;
}
?>
<p>The program says <?= hello("World") ?>.</p>
<script>
    alert("And here is some JS code"); // also colored
</script>
</textarea></form>

    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "application/x-httpd-php",
        indentUnit: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        enterMode: "keep",
        tabMode: "shift"
      });
    </script>
```

It's a simple as pointing `CodeMirror.fromTextArea` to the text area you want to highlight and (optionally) setting options to finetune its behaviour.

Comment: i just had a look at it..i am not so good at js...how should i merge it with my code..i jsut edited my question and posted the code